# STDERR: Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:build-python37' locally

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using the serverless framework with GCP to deploy my cloud functions. I am running into this issue that while running command serverless deploy it is throwing the error as follows

```
Serverless: Generated requirements from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/requirements.txt in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/31d5a3a03f3d66402b20d9de9af44c55ef7d81ac685a1682ee07e7108d6547ef_slspyc/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python37
Serverless: Using download cache directory /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc
Serverless: Running docker run --rm -v /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/31d5a3a03f3d66402b20d9de9af44c55ef7d81ac685a1682ee07e7108d6547ef_slspyc\:/var/task\:z -v /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc\:/var/useDownloadCache\:z lambci/lambda\:build-python37 /bin/sh -c 'chown -R 0\\:0 /var/useDownloadCache && python37 -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt --cache-dir /var/useDownloadCache && chown -R 112\\:116 /var/task && chown -R 112\\:116 /var/useDownloadCache'...
 
 Error ---------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: STDOUT: 
  
  STDERR: Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:build-python37' locally
  docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for lambci/lambda:build-python37 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
  See 'docker run --help'.
  
      at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:331:13
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at installRequirements (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:318:28)
      at installRequirementsIfNeeded (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:576:3)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/lib/pip.js:655:29)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.tryCatcher (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

But this image is already installed in my local docker.

```
lambci/lambda                                                     latest                                     50dafa7488c4        2 years ago         712MB

lambci/lambda                                                     build-python3.7                            d115d451cc01        6 months ago        2.35GB
```

But still its throwing error.
Here is the my serverless.yml file

```
service: demo

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .gitignore
    - .git/**
    - .idea/**

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

plugins:
  - serverless-google-cloudfunctions
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-prune-plugin
provider:
  name: google
  runtime: python37
  project:  ${opt:project}
  credentials: ${opt:cred}
  environment:
    bucket_name: ${opt:bucket_name}

functions:
  demoNew:
    handler: get_version
    events:
      - http: path
```

can any one help me?

Comment: Is that a typo? It looks like the image tag has a dot in the version:  build-python3.7 but the error shows without the dot lambci/lambda:build-python37

Comment: No serverless automatically pick the version of it. so there is no build tag like that without dot.

Comment: I understand that it picks the version automatically but as shown in the error message, if you try to "docker run lambci/lambda:build-python37" locally you will run into the same issue since this image tag build-python37 does not exist.

Comment: @CaioT do you have any solution to this problem? I am really frustrated on this problem.

Comment: Can you add the serverless yaml file to your post?

Comment: @CaioT I have added that.